# Mongo DB unknown Error?

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb, mongo-java

I am new to Mongo DB I have to implement it in java. I went through may slides but I am confused what is happening. I executed a small java program using mongo DB but it is not working?

**My java code:**

```
    public class MongoDbTesting {

    public void connectingMongo() throws UnknownHostException, MongoException{
    Mongo m = new Mongo("localhost" , 27017); //mongo object
    DB db = m.getDB("todo");
    System.out.println("Connected");
    //making a collection object which is table when compared to sql
    DBCollection items = db.getCollection("items"); 
    System.out.println("items got");

    //to work with document we need basicDbObject       
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    System.out.println("Created mongoObject");
    //insert in mongo
    query.put("priority", "highest");
    items.insert(query);
    System.out.println("Inserted");     
      //Cursor, which is like rs in sql
    DBCursor cursor = items.find();
    System.out.println("items got");
    //print highest priority items

    while(cursor.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(cursor.hasNext());
    }   
    } 
    }
```

**The output is:**
 it is getting printed continuously as

true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true

I cant figure out what is happening. i want to insert some data into the collection "items"
also if i want to know how to use Mongo in java. I know mysql well but shifting to mongo I cant relate both in queries. What is "query.put" is doing? Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got yourself an infinite loop because you forgot to call cursor.next() inside the while loop.

Comment: I tried but its saying that i need to wait for 3 min to accept a answer. so only. sorry. 1 more min to go. please.

Comment: It's marked as an answer now, no need to apologize. I learned something new today - it takes a couple of minutes for an answer to get accepted, interesting.

Comment: yup yes. stackoverflow rocks. Please come often and help people like me. its been a great pride learning from you all. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
System.out.println(cursor.next());
```

rather than

```
System.out.println(cursor.hasNext());
```

...

Comment: +1 and if i have a option to mark both are right i will definitely do that but my hands are tied. sorry for that.